# Lower Rank Matrix Approximation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a p x p matrix with spectral decompositon $\sum_{i=1}^{p} \lambda_i e_i e_{i}^{'}$ and B = a q x q matrix $\sum_{i=1}^{q} \lambda_i e_i e_{i}^{'}$, 1<= q < p.
Where $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_p \in \mathbb{R}$.

How can show that $tr[(A-B)(A-B)^{'} = \sum_{i = q+1}^{p} \lambda_i^2$?

So far I derived: $\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{k} (a_{ij} - b_{ij})^2 = tr[(A-B)(A-B)^{'}$.

And

$(A-B) = \sum_{i=q+1}^{p}\lambda_i e_i e_{i}^{'}$  and

$(A-B)^{'} = (\sum_{i=q+1}^{p}\lambda_i e_i e_{i}^{'})^{'}$ => $\sum_{i=q+1}^{p}\lambda_i e_i^{'} e_{i}$ => $\sum_{i=q+1}^{p}\lambda_i$

Im not sure where to go from here since when I multiply $(A-B)(A-B)^{'}$ I get this extra term $\sum_{i=q+1}^{p}\lambda_i^2 e_i^{'} e_{i}$. Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Your expression for $(A - B)'$ is incorrect. Note that $(PQ)' = Q'P'$, which means that $(e_ie_i')' = e_ie_i'$.

Comment: Note that your statement regarding $(A - B)'$ seems to imply that the transpose of a square matrix is a scalar, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Also, you haven't said so, but I suspect that $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_p$ are meant to be real numbers in this context. Please [edit] your question to explicitly say whether this is the case

Answer (score 1):

When you correctly compute $(A - B)'$, you find that $(A - B)' = A-B$. This makes sense: since $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian matrices, so is $A - B$.

With that, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}[(A-B)(A-B)'] &= 
\operatorname{tr}\left[
\left(\sum_{i}\lambda_i e_ie_i'\right)
\left(\sum_j \lambda_je_je_j'\right)\right]
\\ & = 
\sum_{i,j}\operatorname{tr}\left[
\lambda_i \lambda_j e_ie_i'e_je_j'\right]
= \sum_{i}\operatorname{tr}\left[
\lambda_i^2 e_ie_i'\right] = \sum_i\lambda_i^2.
\end{align}
$$